# NFS User ID mapping works for some uid only

Tags: permissions, mount, nas, nfs, synology

I try to setup NFS access on my Synology NAS. For historical reasons the uid on my client and my server do not match. I understood that NFSv4 could allow me to elegantly solve this issue, to the price of understanding how to use idmap (although, it does not seem to work **that** well on Synology NAS: [mount-synology-nfsv4-export-with-id-mapping](https://superuser.com/questions/1131727/mount-synology-nfsv4-export-with-id-mapping)).

Anyway, I was happy enough with the solution proposed by suprjami at [user-id-mapping-with-nfs-on-synology-nas](https://superuser.com/questions/860553/user-id-mapping-with-nfs-on-synology-nas) (and I found several other places on the web describing the same technique) which consists in using all_squash option to map any user on the client to a given user on the server. The only possibility provided by the graphical user interface of the NAS is to map to a user called admin that has uid=1024.

This works fine:

```
NAS-192.168.0.2 # cat /etc/exports
/volume1/photo  192.168.0.10(rw,async,no_wdelay,all_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1024,anongid=100)
```

On my client laptop with IP 192.168.0.10:

```
laptop-192.168.0.10 # mount 192.168.0.2:/volume1/photo /mnt/nas
laptop-192.168.0.10 # ls -l /mnt
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 juin  22 17:08 nas
```

I can list, read and write files in /mnt/nas and everything is creddited to user 1024, as expected.

Now, my problem: I would like to map not to admin but to my local user on the NAS, which has user id 1026 as can be checked on the NAS:

```
NAS-192.168.0.2 # id infisxc
uid=1026(infisxc) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```

So, I simply change the anonuid value on /etc/exports on the server:

```
NAS-192.168.0.2 # cat /etc/exports
/volume1/photo  192.168.0.10(rw,async,no_wdelay,all_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1026,anongid=100)
NAS-192.168.0.2 # exportfs -ra
```

Now, on the client side, the mount still succeeds but with no permission at all:

```
laptop-192.168.0.10 # mount 192.168.0.2:/volume1/photo /mnt/nas
laptop-192.168.0.10 # ls -l /mnt
d---------  5 root root 4096 juin  22 17:08 nas
```

And unsurpisingly, I cannot list the content of the folder.

It seems to me that I am doing all right, but I might be forgetting something. Any advise would be welcome.

Just to be complete, I have a DS414j NAS from Synology with DSM 6.1.2-15132.

Comment: Did you figure this out at any point?

Comment: No. I am currently still living with my setting as the admin user. Still thankfully welcoming any suggestion.